# Q spread TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: node.js, q

```
exports.getOrder = function(id) {
    return getCache(id)
        .then(function(cache) {
            return [
                getCustomer(cache.customer),
                getInfo(cache.customer)
            ];
        })
        .spread(mergeData)
}

function mergeData(a, b) {
    return a;
}
```

Any ideas why I get a type error using spread? Both functions (`getCustomer`, `getInfo`) return a `Q.Promise`.

Edit:

```
exports.getOrder = function(id) {
    return getCache(id)
        .then(function(cache) {
            return Q.all([getCustomer(cache.customer),getInfo(cache.customer)]);
        })
        .spread(mergeAuditData)
}
```

I also have tested this way without success and the same result.

Edit2:

```
exports.getOrder = function(id) {
    return getCache(id)
        .then(function(cache) {
            return Q.all([
                getCustomer(cache.customer),
                getInfo(cache.customer)
            ]);
        })
        .then(function(a) {
            return a // contains: [[result Customer], [result Info]]
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        })
}
```

Edit3:

```
exports.getOrder = function(id) {
    return getCache(id)
        .then(function(cache) {
            return [
                getCustomer(cache.customer),
                getInfo(cache.customer)
            ];
        })
        .spread(function(a,b) {
            console.log(a);
            console.log(b);
            return a
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        })
}
```

Edit4:

```
function getCache(id) {
    return Cache.findOne({id:id});
}
```

Edit5:

```
function getCache(id) {
    var query = Cache.findOne({id:id});
    return query.exec();

    //return Q(11061);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i havent tested though but can you try and replace your code with

```
module.exports.getOrder = function(id) {
return getCache(id)
    .then(function(cache) {
        return [
            getCustomer(cache.customer),
            getInfo(cache.customer)
        ];
    })
    .spread(function(a,b) {
        console.log(a);
        console.log(b);
        return a
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    })
}
```

Comment: I have edited first post with another solution. I will test yours and give some feedback.

Comment: is it an issue of ES6?

Comment: interesting...in `a` there will be both results and `b` is undefined.

Comment: edit the answer,as you only expect the result in your **.then** function as error can be handled through **.catch**, thatswhy _a_ has result and _b_ is undefined.

Comment: yes, and I want split the results with spread...but spread only throws the type error

Comment: i have done a little amendment in the code, just check,i hope it will work fine.

Comment: no, webstorm says it's not supported. I updated my version again...can't understand why spread is not working. in `a` there is an array with the results of `getCustomer` and `getInfo`. Isn't it the format spread expects?

Comment: You are right, we pass array in `spread`. You tried `.all().then(function([a, b]))` ?

Comment: yes I have tested...but destructuring assignment is not supportet by my javascript version.

Comment: can you replace `.all().then()` with `.spread(a, b)` and check it again!

Comment: this is the result resolved in a: [ [ { customer: 'XXX GmbH',
      id: 1000,
      address: 'xxx Street 11, XXX'' } ],
  [ { telefax: '(xxx) xxxx'} ] ]

Comment: I have replaced it with spread: result is again: TypeError: undefined is not a function. I don't get it. For actual code see Edit3

Comment: I have edited the answe again, can you please try, the edit is with refrence to your edit3.

Comment: isn't it the same code like Edit3? Still the following error:TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: you put module along with exports, i mean replace exports with  `module.exports`

Comment: maybe the problems comes from the first `getCache` function? (Edit4)

Comment: I use `exec()` to use mongoose promises. But that did not solve the problem. Returning the id with 'Q(11061)' makes spread working. Any ideas? (Edit5)